# ERROR in ./src/app/svg.component.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg.component.svg'

Tags: angular

There is a live example from the official doc thats not working:
https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/template-syntax/stackblitz.html

The live example error says:
Import error, can't find file: ./svg.component.svg

If I download the example and npm install it, I got the error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/svg.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './svg.component.svg' in 'C:\Users\Elias\Desktop\New folder\src\app'
```

The svg.component.ts has this portion of code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-svg',
  templateUrl: './svg.component.svg',
```

It seems that the component is asking for an .svg file. I don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to reference a file that don't exist, and you are trying to reference an svg template from a css which also won't work.

Just add a `.svg` file containing your svg template to your directory and that should work fine. See the image below.

[image]

Comment: Do you know where do I get that file from?

Comment: You can use any svg file you have..see examples here https://undraw.co/illustrations